# Why is tf.math.sqrt executing on the CPU and not on the GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am running `tensorflow-gpu` in python 3 on a Windows 10 machine.

I have a GPU, and it is the default processor for `tensorflow` to run on.

When I use `tf.math.sqrt` or `tf.math.pow`, I see that it is executing that operation on the CPU, not the GPU. Why?

MWE:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
x = tf.Variable(1j)
```

Then I do:

```
tf.math.sqrt(x)
```

But I get:

```
Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op Sqrt in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

Comment: Hi!checked in TF 2.5  colab , code is working fine . providing gist for reference. https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/822b76ad57d873e95dc48e38dd929143/stack_.ipynb